# no documentation for SecurityGuard.MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to add a good authozation package to an MVC4 application.
I proceeded to Install-Package SecurityGuard.mvc4 via the package manage console of Visual Studio 2012.
After installing it, I have no idea how to implement it.
Is there a Users Guide, Sample Application, or Tutorial I could use?
Thanks, any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed this package too, but this uses the old Membership scheme, mean 11 tables.
If SecurityGuard were built within the new MVC4 specification, this would have to use only 5 tables. Anyway, I've tried to find the official documentation but I think that the only one's is the source code itself.

Answer (score 0):

At the github page, the developer continues to actively support it. And it's mentioned there's a wiki, here: https://github.com/kahanu/Security-Guard/wiki